# Reposurgeon gives me a SyntaxError when using exec, why?

Tags: python, reposurgeon

Using [`reposurgeon`](http://www.catb.org/esr/reposurgeon/) and trying to extend its functionality, I am faced with:

```
reposurgeon: invalid syntax in extension function
```

which translates to a `SyntaxError` extension raised from the `execfile()` call in `RepoSurgeon.do_exec()`. What gives? The code I am trying to `exec` is as simple as:

```
print "Hello world"
```

I have also used the Python CLI and `execfile` and there are no complaints whatsoever?

Used version: `reposurgeon` 3.10

Answer (score 1):

This one took me a while to figure out, which is why I am posting it here.

The key is indeed in the single line of code we're trying to "source". While this is perfectly valid Python 2.x code, `reposurgeon` uses the `print` function from Python 3.x by doing:

```
from __future__ import print_function
```

Which causes `print` to **require** the use of parentheses, as it makes `print` a function instead of a statement.

Obviously we're running our extension code in the context of `reposurgeon`, which means that we're dependent on the rules it defines.

See [this document](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/pyporting.html#from-future-import-print-function).

Hence the following will work just fine:

```
print("Hello world")
```