# How to replace existing Python class methods of (or otherwise extend) RepoSurgeon by means of 'exec' and 'eval'?

Tags: python, reposurgeon

[The documentation](http://www.catb.org/~esr/reposurgeon/reposurgeon.html) (at the time of this writing) on the topic is scarce. How can I extend reposurgeon functionality if the use of macros (`define`) isn't sufficient for my purposes?

The only clues it gives is that:

> The code has full access to all internal data structures. Functions defined are accessible to later **eval** calls.

But what does that even mean?

We also learn that:

> Typically this will be a call to a function defined by a previous exec. The variables _repository and _selection will have the obvious values. Note that _selection will be a list of integers, not objects.

Answer (score 2):

### Preliminary note

I will use italic inline code (*`like this`*) to denote Python code and "normal" inline code (`like this`) to denote RepoSurgeon commands. For code blocks, an introductory description should provide the context, i.e. whether it's a RepoSurgeon command or Python code.

This writeup discusses version 3.10 of RepoSurgeon, which is the latest as of this writing.

### Intro

[RepoSurgeon](http://www.catb.org/~esr/reposurgeon/) is written in Python and explicitly allows to *`execfile()`* other Python code within it. The syntax of the RepoSurgeon command for it is:

```
exec </path/to/python-source.py
```

This much we can gather from the documentation.

We can use this from within a lift script or on the RepoSurgeon prompt.

### Where does your code end up?

As already pointed out [in this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25146005/476371) you need to observe the rules imposed by the surrounding code when running in the context of RepoSurgeon. In particular **your Python code is going to be executed within the context of the *`__main__.RepoSurgeon`* instance**, so this is the first thing to keep in mind.

You also will always have to give a selection with `eval`. It doesn't appear to be legit to give no selection and expect an implied "all selected" as for `list` or other built-in commands, although you can arguably leverage `exec` to change that behavior as we'll see in a bit.

Also make sure to use `eval myfunc()` and not `eval myfunc`. Obviously *`myfunc`* is a valid Python statement, but don't expect it to do anything. You'll have to *call* the function. Everything after `eval` is handed straight to Python's *`eval()`*.

While *`execfile()`* (`exec` as a RepoSurgeon) runs you can abuse the context you're running in and reference *`self`*, which is the instance of *`__main__.RepoSurgeon`* mentioned above. More about this later.

### A first trivial example

Consider the following Python code that introduces a new unbound function *`myfunc`*:

```
def myfunc():
    print("Hello world!")
```

and the following command issued at the RepoSurgeon prompt:

```
exec </path/to/your/python-code.py
```

followed by:

```
=O eval myfunc()
```

This will yield the expected output:

```
Hello world!
```

You may want to use a different selection from mine, though. Whichever suits your needs.

**Note:** In any case even an empty selection will still result in your Python code being called! For example the selection `=I` in my loaded repo is empty, but I will still see the output as produced above. It's simply important to give *any* selection to have your code invoked.

### Exploring the context in which our Python code runs

With the above trivial example we can check *whether* it works. Now on to explore what we can access besides *`_selection`* and *`_repository`* mentioned in the documentation.

Changing the function *`myfunc`* to:

```
def myfunc():
    from pprint import pprint
    pprint(globals())
    pprint(locals())
```

should give us a feeling what we're dealing with.

After the change (and saving it ;)) simply re-run:

```
exec </path/to/your/python-code.py
```

followed by:

```
=O eval myfunc()
```

you should see a dump of the contents of `globals()` and `locals()`.

You will notice that even in the context of the `eval` you can still access *`self`* (part of the *`globals()`* in this case). That's pretty useful.

As I mentioned before, you can also modify the instance of *`__main__.RepoSurgeon`* within which your code runs (more about this below).

In order to see all methods etc, use *`dir(self)`* in your function (or at the top-level when `exec`-ing the Python code file).

So simply add this line to *`myfunc`*:

```
dir(self)
```

making it:

```
def myfunc():
    from pprint import pprint
    pprint(globals())
    pprint(locals())
    dir(self)
```

after invoking the `exec` and `eval` commands again (on Linux recall it as you would in the shell using cursor <kbd>Up</kbd>) you should now see most of the functions listed you'd also be able to find the the RepoSurgeon code.

**Note:** simply re-running RepoSurgeon's `exec` command followed by another `eval myfunc()` will now add the output of the attributes of *`__main__.RepoSurgeon`*.

While all of this is cool so far and should give you a feeling for how to run your own Python code in RepoSurgeon, you can also **replace** existing *`__main__.RepoSurgeon`* methods. Read on.

### Hooking into RepoSurgeon and replacing functionality

With the access to *`self`* comes the power to *add* functionality *and* to modify existing functionality.

*`RepoSurgeon.precmd`* looks like a worthy candidate for this. It's the method that gets called prior to running the actual command and performs a syntax check as well as setting the selection set that is so vital in many RepoSurgeon commands.

What we need is the prototype of *`precmd`*. Here it is:

```
def precmd(self, line):
```

What was the trick again in replacing method? [Alex Martelli's answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1015405) leads the way ...

We can simply use this as our (complete) Python file to `exec`:

```
if self:
    if not 'orig_precmd' in self.__dict__:
        setattr(self, 'orig_precmd', self.precmd) # save original precmd
    def myprecmd(self, line):
        print("[pre-precmd] '%s'" % line)
        orig_precmd = getattr(self, 'orig_precmd')
        return self.orig_precmd(line)
    setattr(self, 'precmd', myprecmd.__get__(self, self.__class__))
```

- The *`if self:`* is merely to scope our code.
- The check for 'orig_precmd' ensures we're not overwriting the value of this attribute *again* upon subsequent calls to `exec`.
- *`myprecmd(self, line):`* contains our version of *`__main__.RepoSurgeon.precmd`*. The awesome new functionality it adds is to parrot the command that was entered.
- Last but not least the second *`setattr()`* simply overrides the *`__main__.RepoSurgeon.precmd`* with our version. Any subsequent call RepoSurgeon makes to *`self.precmd()`* will go through our "hook" now.

Remember, we are overriding internal code of RepoSurgeon, so tread carefully and don't do anything silly. The code is very readable, albeit a whopping 10k LoC.

Next time you issue any command, you should have it parroted back at you. Consider the following (RepoSurgeon prompt plus excerpt from output):

```
reposurgeon% =O list
[pre-precmd] '=O list'
```

`=O list` is the command I entered and `[pre-precmd] '=O list'` the output it yields (followed by the actual output, since I am calling the original implementation of *`__main__.RepoSurgeon.precmd`* in my version).

### Conclusion

The RepoSurgeon commands `exec` and `eval` provide a powerful means to override existing functionality and add new functionality in RepoSurgeon.

The hook example is a superset of "simply" extending RepoSurgeon by using `eval` with a previously `exec`'d function. It allows to sneak code into the guts of RepoSurgeon and bend it to our will where ever it has shortcomings (of which I have only found a handful so far).

Kudos to ESR for this design decision. There is no need for a plugin framework this way.