# How to add a new function to RepoSurgeon (just like dsc or amp or min)

Tags: python-2.7, reposurgeon

This is a specialized version of: [How to replace existing Python class methods of (or otherwise extend) RepoSurgeon by means of 'exec' and 'eval'?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25150613/476371)

How can one add a new function to RepoSurgeon using the `exec` facility (i.e. without editing the upstream code) to add a new function, augmenting existing functionality.

Problem: if you are using RepoSurgeon and you call a function from your script or on the command line and the function throws an exception, this will throw off nested function calls.

Example: you want to find all fossils on a branch by branch name in a single function. The following compound command will do the job for a branch named `BRANCH`:

```
@dsc(@min(/BRANCH/)) list
```

This works fine if `BRANCH` exists. But what if it doesn't? In such a case RepoSurgeon will get quite angry with us and throw an exception:

```
@dsc(@min(/NO_SUCH_BRANCH/)) list
[...]
ValueError: min() arg is an empty sequence
```

The problem is that this means that your whole lift script will get derailed.

What to do?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps one of the easiest solutions is to write your own function and bundle the call sequence of `@dsc(@min(...))` while guarding against exceptions.

Assuming you have a lift script, embed the following here-doc as argument to `exec` into it:

```
exec <<EOF
    if self:
        def brpdsc_factory(recov):
            Recoverable = recov
            def brpdsc_handler(self, subarg):
                if not subarg:
                    raise Recoverable("function @brpdsc() called with selection that resolves to empty set")
                minset =      set([])
                descendants = set([])
                try:
                    minset = self.min_handler(subarg)
                except ValueError as e:
                    raise Recoverable("invalid value passed to function @min()")
                try:
                    descendants = self.dsc_handler(minset)
                except:
                    raise Recoverable("the implicit call to @dsc() failed")
                return descendants
            return brpdsc_handler
        brpdsc_handler = brpdsc_factory(Recoverable)
        setattr(self, 'brpdsc_handler', brpdsc_handler.__get__(self, self.__class__))
EOF
```

This implants the local function `brpdsc_handler` as class member of the same name of `class RepoSurgeon` and makes a function `@brpdsc` immediately available to scripts or the command prompt.

The factory function exists to carry over the name for `Recoverable` which is an exception class defined in the `reposurgeon` script but not available to our code anymore after the `exec` has finished. Other symbols can be carried over the same way.

Now all that can happen is that we receive:

```
reposurgeon: function @brpdsc() called with selection that resolves to empty set
```

from RepoSurgeon after attempting to run `@brpdsc/NO_SUCH_BRANCH/) list`.